Lifting problem in group cohomology (coefficient change)
Disclaimer: I do not know much about group cohomology except from the topological point of view.
Let $G$ be a group. We can consider the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and the canonical composition $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[G]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$. Given an element in $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, I would like to produce a lift to $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}[G])$. The obstruction is the (possibly non-vanishing) term $H^3(G;\text{ker}(\phi))$ in the associated Bockstein sequence. If $BG$ is a CW-complex of dimension $2$, this term clearly vanishes. My questions are:
(1) Are there any weaker assumptions on $G$ that assure $H^3(G;\text{ker}(\phi))=0$?
(2) If not, are there (good) ways to classify those elements in $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ that we can still lift to $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}[G])$?

Regarding question (1): If I am not mistaken, I believe you can show that $\ker(\phi)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. If we then additionally have that $H_3(G;\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion and that $\text{Ext}^1(H_2(G;\mathbb{Z}), \ker(\phi)) \cong 0$, then by the UCT we'd get that $H^3(G; \ker(\phi)) \cong 0$. Not sure how helpful this really is though.

@jasnee I am not sure since the standard UCT in general only works for PIDs. Generally, $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is no PID (and hence I don't know whether $\text{ker}(\phi)$) is. The UCT spectral sequence might give some results, though.

Oh yeah that's true, I missed that!

If $G$ is finite, $H^n(G;Z[G])=0$ for $n>0$. In general, you don't want $H^3(G; \mathrm{ker}(\phi))$ to vanish, but rather the map $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H^3(G; \mathrm{ker}(\phi))$ to be zero, which would imply that $H^3(G;\mathbb{Z})$ has no 2-torsion. I don't see any easy sufficient condition though.
